# How can I translate the field group description?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have created two field groups on the manage form display tab for a content type. I have added some description also.

On the interface translation, I can translate the field group labels but there I can't translate the description of a field group. As when I search the description there I can't find any results.

I also checked it in the config translation but field group is not present on that page.

Is there any way I can translate the field group translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no proper UI for this yet, but field groups are config, so you should be able to translate all strings by creating/editing translated versions of those config files.

First, export your current config, e.g. `drush config:export`

Then, in your `config/sync` directory look for files like `core.entity_form_display.ENTITY.BUNDLE.FORMMODE.yml`. In those files you will see a structure like

```
langcode: ISO2CODE
status: true
depenencies:
  config:
    - ...
third_party_settings:
  field_group:
    GROUP_ID:
      children:
        - field_foo
        - field_bar
      label: MY_GROUP_LABEL
      format_settings:
        description: 'MY DESCRIPTION'
...some more stuff...
```

The `third_party_settings/field_group` contains your group labels in your primary language. To translate a label, create a file `language/LANGCODE/core.entity_form_display.ENTITY.BUNDLE.FORMMODE.yml` below your `config/sync` directory.

This file must contain the same structure as the one in the main config file, but remove everything that is not translateable:

```
third_party_settings:
  field_group:
    GROUP_ID:
      label: MY_TRANSLATED_LABEL
      format_settings:
        description: 'MY TRANSLATED DESCRIPTION'
```

Finally, reimport the config with the translated labels, e.g. `drush config:import`